# Spark Dataframe - Implement Oracle NVL Function while joining

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to implement NVL function in spark while joining two dataframes.

Input Dataframes :

```
ds1.show()
---------------
|key  | Code  |
---------------
|2    | DST   |
|3    | CPT   |
|null | DTS   |
|5    | KTP   |
---------------

ds2.show()
------------------
|key  | PremAmt |
------------------
|2     | 300   |
|-1    | -99   |
|5     | 567   |
------------------
```

Need to implement "LEFT JOIN NVL(DS1.key, -1) = DS2.key" .
So I have written like this, but NVL or Coalesce function is missing .so it returned wrong values.

How to incorporate "NVL" in spark dataframes ?

```
// nvl function is missing, so wrong output
ds1.join(ds1,Seq("key"),"left_outer")

-------------------------
|key  | Code  |PremAmt  |
-------------------------
|2    | DST   |300      |
|3    | CPT   |null     |
|null | DTS   |null     |
|5    | KTP   |567      |
-------------------------
```

Expected Result :

```
-------------------------
|key  | Code  |PremAmt  |
-------------------------
|2    | DST   |300      |
|3    | CPT   |null     |
|null | DTS   |-99      |
|5    | KTP   |567      |
-------------------------
```

Comment: `ds1.na.fill(-1, $"key").join(ds2 , Seq("key") , "leftouter")` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know one complex way.

```
 val df = df1.join(df2, coalesce(df1("key"), lit(-1)) === df2("key"), "left_outer")
```

You should rename column name "key" of one df, and drop the column after join.

Answer (score 5):

### An implementation of nvl in Scala

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column;
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{when, lit};

def nvl(ColIn: Column, ReplaceVal: Any): Column = {
  return(when(ColIn.isNull, lit(ReplaceVal)).otherwise(ColIn))
}
```

Now you can use nvl as you would use any other function for data frame manipulation, like

```
val NewDf = DF.withColumn("MyColNullsReplaced", nvl($"MyCol", "<null>"))
```

Obviously, `Replaceval` must be of the correct type. The example above assumes `$"MyCol"` is of type string.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
intermediateDF.select(col("event_start_timestamp"),
        col("cobrand_id"),
        col("rule_name"),
        col("table_name"),
        coalesce(col("dimension_field1"),lit(0)),
        coalesce(col("dimension_field2"),lit(0)),
        coalesce(col("dimension_field3"),lit(0)),
        coalesce(col("dimension_field4"),lit(0)),
        coalesce(col("dimension_field5"),lit(0))
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

## The answer is use NVL, this code in python works

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[1]").appName("CommonMethods").getOrCreate()
```

**Note: SparkSession is being bulit in a "chained" fashion,ie. 3 methods are being applied in teh same line**

## Read CSV file

```
df = spark.read.csv('C:\\tableausuperstore1_all.csv',inferSchema='true',header='true')

df.createOrReplaceTempView("ViewSuperstore")
```

## The ViewSuperstore can be ued for SQL NOW

```
print("*trace1-nvl")

df = spark.sql("select nvl(state,'a') testString, nvl(quantity,0) testInt  from ViewSuperstore where state='Florida' and OrderDate>current_date() ")

df.show()

print("*trace2-FINAL")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.select(expr("nvl(colname,'ZZ')"))
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?